# Mouse cursor freezes sometimes after Dell has been asleep

Tags: 18.04, dell, touchpad

I have a Dell XPS 15 9500 and just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it. It mostly works okay, but (as always) there are a few strange things that it does that I'm hoping to fix. The most annoying thing:

I've noticed that this problem seems to happen after the computer has been asleep a while. When it wakes it will behave normally for a while, but then sometimes the mouse cursor just freezes. I can still type and everything else seems to function but the touchpad just doesn't move the mouse. I have to do a REISUB shutdown.

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Why 18.04? Have you installed Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I tried 20.04 but strange things were happening on boot (black screen with top left cursor). I saw other people online talking about the same problem with 20.04. I went to 18.04 and I didn't have this problem anymore.
I haven't installed Nvidia drivers, but I did remove them when I was trying to fix the 20.04 issue.

Comment: Installing Nvidia drivers -and- disabling Secure Boot in UEFI is what actually solves the problems you had and are having.

Comment: I have the exact same issue plaguing my Dell laptop since 20.04 (and possibly earlier), the above solution does not work for me. Nvidia drivers are also up to date as well tried multiple versions